# Ripple XRP Ledger - How much data can i put in the memo field

Tags: xrp, rippled

What is the limit on the data that i can put in the `memo` field.
I seem to be not able to find that anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The memo field can contain no more than 1KB of data. More information can be found on this page:

https://xrpl.org/transaction-common-fields.html#memos-field